# How to return 'For XML' and 'For JSON' conditionally in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to have a stored procedure that can return either JSON, XML, or tabular data based on the value of a parameter.

So for example,

```
DECLARE @ReturnFormat = 'XML'
```

would return:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
FOR XML PAT('MyPath'), TYPE, ROOT('MyRoot')
```

and if `@ReturnFormat = 'JSON'`, it would return

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable   
FOR JSON PATH
```

and if `@ReturnFormat = 'Tabular'`, it would return

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
```

But I don't want to copy/paste the SQL obviously. How would I make a conditional return like that?

Comment: If your statements aren't overly simple, there will be differences in your SELECTs, which will **enforce two different statements in any case**... If you do not want to copy the underlying logic (JOINs, computed columns...) just use a VIEW (or a temp tabe or a table variable to hold an intermediate result. Then create two selects within a simple `IF` structure.

Answer (score 3):

What's the problem in it being simply:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProc
  @ReturnFormat varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF @ReturnFormat = 'XML'
    your XML SELECT
  ELSE IF @ReturnFormat = 'JSON'
    your JSON SELECT
  ELSE IF @ReturnFormat = 'Tabular'
    your tabular SELECT
  /* If needed, add an ELSE. */

END;
```

Comment: You can `SELECT` from an view with the underlying logic to simplify the proc

Comment: That is what I was trying to avoid; I would need to copy/paste the entire select statement in each of the 'else' conditions and some of the queries are quite complicated so it would be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @user197505 - as *elizabk* said you could wrap your format selects in views for easier maintenance down the road but I don't think there's another silver bullet for your problem.

Comment: I would just do this IF ELSE logic and then call another stored proc (or function) which has the regular SELECT FROM sql (tabular) to avoid code duplication. Another option is to have 2 stored procs, for XML and for JSON, which call the third stored proc which is the regular SELECT. That would make it more clear that the SP is returning completely different output (versus having an optional @ReturnFormat input).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @ReturnFormat varchar(4);

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT {Columns} FROM MyTable' +
           CASE @ReturnFormat WHEN 'JSON' THEN N' FOR JSON PATH;'
                              WHEN 'XML' THEN N' FOR XML PATH (''MyPath''),TYPE,ROOT(''MyRoot'');'
           END;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Note you should also declare your columns, hence you'll need to replace `{Columns}` with the relevant columns.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is against policy for our company

Comment: What do you mean "against policy" @user197505? Why?

Comment: Our company doesn't want dynamic sql because it can't be optimized beforehand by the database engine and is quite difficult to maintain and debug when it gets complicated.

Comment: @user197505 what? That's nonsense. A well parametrised Dynamic statement **will** have it's query plan cached and reused. For the example above, both queries will have a cached version which the instance can make reuse of. As for debugging, again it's incredibly simple. Just use `SELECT @SQL;` or `PRINT @SQL` and you can easily debug the statement. The **mistake** people make is not formatting their dynamic SQL. Yes, a dynamic statement that is 1000+ characters long would be hard to debug if it's all written on 1 line, but that's not the SQL's fault that's the developer's for bad formatting.

Comment: But, do you *really* think the above statement is hard to debug? That's probably one of the most simple dynamic statements that could be written. And, from the data engine's point of view, it only has 2 plans to cache as well (and XML version and a JSON version), so after both versions have been run you already have cached plans for the XML and JSON outputs. "Difficultly to debug", and "can't be optimised" are completely untrue for this example, however, they are untrue for others anyway, provided the SQL is well designed; but then the question is why *isn't* it well designed?